How to move files matching patterns from file?
I have a file storage directory used together with a MySQL DB.
Some of the files in the directory are orphaned (i.e. created by mistake, deleted in the DB but not on disk, otherwise not used).
I was able to generate list of such files without file extension but now what's the best way to move them out of the storage directory. The problem is that the storage is multi-level, so I have to find each file first somehow.
Sample of the orphan list content (200K lines in total):
10218
10219
10220
10221
10370
10371
10372
10373
10374

Directory structure (example):

If you wonder how I ended up with such a file:

first, saved list of files in directory recursively to one file per https://stackoverflow.com/a/5456136/505984
secondly, dumped DB table id's to another file with MySQL CLI (because each filename without the extension matches the DB record ID)
diff'ed the two files as advised here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25407317/505984


I will concentrate on making the selection because you said:

The problem is that the storage is multi-level, so I have to find each file first somehow.

Assuming the bash shell:
find /path/to/data/ -type f \
| grep -f <( awk '{print $0".pdf"}' tmp/orphans ) \
| further processing goes here, possibly with xargs

Clarification:
find makes a list of all files in the tree.
grep -f somefile applies a filter to the piped output of find
<( something ) is an ephemeral file
awk '{print $0".pdf"}' appends every line in the orphans list with ".pdf", so grep -f does not match directory names
tmp/orphans is the input list of orphans

I'm not sure where to go from here.  First, not all files are .pdf's. Secondly I ran find httpdocs/E4/data/ -type f | grep -f <( awk '{print $0".pdf"}' transfer/orphans.txt ) and it was just eating CPU and not doing anything.

I notice this answer received some downvotes - it seems to me a reasonable pragmatic approach that just needs a bit of tweaking. For instance, awk '{print "/" $0 "\....$"}' to anchor the generated regex (to prevent 456 from matching 123456 for example) and generalize the dot extension. You could also make everything null delimited (print0 ... grep -zf ... xargs -r0) allowing it to handle arbitrary filenames - although that doesn't seem to be necessary based on the OP's data.

@steeldriver the problem is that it's terribly slow. time find httpdocs/E4/data/ -type f | head -n 100 | grep -f <( awk '{print $0"."}' transfer/orphans.txt ) -> real    0m18.560s. On 200K files it would take hours.

Note to self: awk '{print "/"$0"."}' seems to be better

@AntonDuzenko when you're searching for "needle(s)" in "haystack" it's likely the size of "haystack" that determines the search time - unless the files are already indexed somehow (as with plocate/updatedb) then your choice may be between a slow solution and no solution

@steeldriver I agree but then the question arises how to handle "efficient pattern lists" with grep or any other bash utility. Anyway, for my practical use find | grep -f appears to be reasonal solution. I do wonder though if splitting the list into N parts would make things faster or slower.

Default grep configuration goes out of memory. In my case, I need to run it with -F to use the non-regexp search.

It might be faster to insert both the output of find and the orphans list in a database, with indexes on the name part, and do the filtering using something like
ELECT ..... FROM FindList AS F INNER JOIN Orphanlist AS O ON O.namepart = F.namepart ....;

Your question isn't exactly clear, but assuming you want to

turn a list of files without extension into a list of patterns that will match files with arbitrary extensions

pass that list of patterns efficiently to a sequence of find commands


then you could try something like this, using sed and GNU parallel (available from the Ubuntu universe repository):
export srcdir=path/to/data

sed 's/$/.*/' orphans.txt | parallel -I%% --env srcdir -X '
  find "$srcdir" -type f \( %% -false \) -print
' ::: -name :::: - ::: -o

With the -X option, parallel will try to fit as many arguments as possible into each find invocation; the arguments are drawn from three input sources:

the string -name

a line from standard input

the string -o


thus building up an argument list that looks like -name '1406.*' -o -name '6179.*' -o -name '17526.*' -o ... (which you can verify by adding the parallel --dry-run option). The final -false predicate mops up the trailing -o and -I%% changes parallel's replacement string from the default {} so as not to conflict with find's default replacement string.
This is certainly more efficient than running find 200,0000 times - but may not be as efficient as running a single find command and grepping the result, as suggested in this answer. On my 64-bit Ubuntu 24.04 VM it manages to cram a file of 200,0000 integer IDs (generated from the bash $RANDOM variable) into approximately 100 invocations of find.
If that successfully identifies the files, you can change -print to something like -exec mv -vnt "$dstdir" {} + where similar to srcdir you export dstdir=path/to/newdata and pass it to parallel via --env destdir:
export srcdir=path/to/data
export dstdir=path/to/newdata

sed 's/$/.*/' orphans.txt | 
  parallel -I%% --env srcdir --env dstdir -X '
    find "$srcdir" -type f \( %% -false \) -exec mv -vnt "$dstdir" {} +
  ' ::: -name :::: - ::: -o

(you can use -execdir in place of -exec provided $dstdir is an absolute path).

While I'm sure you answer will be helpful to other people, I have to run this on a manageed web server without root permissions. So installing parallel or any other non-standard software is not allowed.
